# Giving a 3D list values from a 2D list in python: list index out of range

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a 3D list with the values of a 2D list. I have developed the code above:

```
ncells=20 
nareas=3 
seed=[[0 for k in range(nareas+1)]for i in range(ncells)]
    
for k in range(nareas+1):
    for i in range(ncells):
        if k==0:
           seed[i][k]=1

numvizinhos=nareas-1
viz=[]
    
for v in range(numvizinhos+1):
    for k in range(nareas+1):
         for i in range(ncells):
              viz[v][i][k]=seed[i][k]
```

But, when i run this i get an error saying: "list index out of range". I was wondering if anyone could help me and if there is other way of assigning values on the 3D list, based on the 2D list.

Thank you!

Comment: `viz` is an empty list. *any* integer value you pass as an index will produce an `IndexError`, so `viz[v][i][k] = seed[i][k]` will cause the error... it's the same as `data = []` then `data[0] = 1`.

Comment: So, one quick fix would be to initialize `viz` the same way you did `seed`, i.e. `viz = [[[0 for k in range(nareas+1)] for i in range(ncells)] for j in range(numvizinhos)]`

Comment: And also, don't use `numvizinhos+1`...although it isn't clear what you intend.

Comment: As an aside, you should likely just use `numpy` here...